# Do I need additional runspace clean up after killing parent process?

Tags: powershell, runspace

I have a very limited understanding of how resource management/garbage collection and similar things work in powershell.

My question is: **is it okay to kill a process that has a running runspace?**

**start.ps1**

```
$moduleOnePath = Join-Path $cwd "moduleOne.exe" -Resolve
$moduleTwoPath = Join-Path $cwd "moduleTwo.exe" -Resolve

$moduleOneProcess = Start-Process $moduleOnePath -PassThru
$moduleTwoProcess = Start-Process $moduleTwoPath -PassThru

$moduleOneProcess.WaitForExit()
$moduleTwoProcess.kill()
```

**moduleTwo.exe** (compiled from `ps` script with [this](https://github.com/aravindvcyber/PS1toEXE); only relevant part shown)

```
  $runspace= [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
  $runspace.Open()
  $powershell= [powershell]::Create()
  $powershell.Runspace = $runspace
  $powershell.AddScript({
     while($true) {
        sleep -s 1;
     }
  }) | Out-Null
```